Shower Valve Identification Help
We bought a "fixer-upper" and I had to demo the bath/shower tile as the grout had failed.
I am trying to identify the shower valve and hoping to buy a bath faucet that is compatible. Looks like I can slightly make out "Moen" on the side.
Trying to avoid replacing the valve as it is above my skill set and budget. Do I have any hope here?
!(https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOTBjhiQHXRjGhl3V2sHJWo9bq_0DS8bhXrdid2nrEGS6nhlpq-kZ8B1HxfeCGYyQ/photo/AF1QipOgQPmh5sME-EP98KSlVotyyE1d10RjDt-34FcI?key=MkV1NUE4alRKSnFrdE52SGFlYnBpbzFreTlPOHNB)
!(https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOTBjhiQHXRjGhl3V2sHJWo9bq_0DS8bhXrdid2nrEGS6nhlpq-kZ8B1HxfeCGYyQ/photo/AF1QipOp_Wh0lsxBHXahtP306MkG0hkmJNNr90iNR2Ud?key=MkV1NUE4alRKSnFrdE52SGFlYnBpbzFreTlPOHNB)
!(https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOTBjhiQHXRjGhl3V2sHJWo9bq_0DS8bhXrdid2nrEGS6nhlpq-kZ8B1HxfeCGYyQ/photo/AF1QipO2wS4zAwUBU0qsjRwuYCmu0as5T9cR0h0xPQiK?key=MkV1NUE4alRKSnFrdE52SGFlYnBpbzFreTlPOHNB)

It is a Moen.  I just had to replace my whole valve, because I couldn't get the cartridge out.    The cartridges are readily available.  If you're going to give replacing the cartridge a shot, best to get a specialty tool for pulling this kind of cartridge.  You need to pull that shim out the top before using the puller, and don't forget to turn off the water.
It's a Moen 1225
Here's a link to Amazon for the after market part.  Any hardware store will have the manufacturers part.
https://a.co/d/03XEKQy2
Oh, and if you just need the handle and plate, etc., those are available at most hardware stores too. They come in kits.

+1, "You need to pull that shim out the top..."; I would call it a "U-shaped clip", rather than a shim...
